# How and When the Serialized Objects are used by the end user

Tags: java, serialization

Some days back I've been interviewed in the Serialization process. As everyone knows Serialization is the process of converting the object into a byte stream and saved into a file.

**Interviewer** : How the end user come to know it is serialized object ??

**Me** : Based on the **serialVersionUID**

**Interviewer** : How he come to know the **serialVersionUID** , because your serializing the object, but how he know that file is the serialized object.

**Me**: Ummmm... ummmm...

My question is when the end user will use that serialized object, and how he will identify this is the serialized object.

Comment: Its done at product/software architecture level. Normally, entities involved at both ends know if they are dealing with serialized objects or not.
The 'how' part?  - Its implementing `Serializable` interface. 
The 'when' part? - whenever u need to store a copy of an object and send it across any other process or system over network.

Comment: *"Serialization is the process of saving the state of the object into a file."* ... this is inaccurate.  Serialization by the JVM Serialization Facility automates the process of converting an object graph into a byte stream.  Of course, the byte stream can be saved to a file, but it needn't be.

Comment: @scottb I've edited my post. Can you tell me the how the end user is used and when it is needed

Comment: Very unclear question. They might be looking for a comment about the file name extension. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433214/file-extension-for-a-serialized-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Interviewer: How the end user come to know it is serialized object?

Strange question.

> Me : Based on the serialVersionUID

Even stranger answer. How does the end user get to see a `serialVersionUID`?

The correct answer as far as I can see is that he *doesn't* 'come to know it'. The end user just operates the application. He doesn't even see code, let alone objects, let alone get to know how they were instantiated. Strange question.

Note that the final sentence above would have been part of my answer.